# How to watch a Directory in HDFS for incoming Files using Python? (Python Script is executed by Docker Container; No Cronjob in HDFS)

Tags: python, docker, hdfs

**Scenario:** My Python Script is running in a docker container which is deployed in rancher (kubernetes cluster). Therefore the container is always running. I want to implement a method which is watching a directory in my HDFS for incoming files. if new files are there , i want the script to execute further actions (preprocessing steps to wrangle data). When the new files have been processed they should be deleted. after that the script is waiting for new incoming files to process them as well. 
Therefore it should not be a cronjob in HDFS. i need the code in the script which is executed by docker container. Currently i am using hdfs cli to connect to my HDFS. For Java I found INotify but i need to do it with python.

Does anybody know a Python Lib or some other possibility to get this going?

Comment: Can you please add more information.If I understand correctly you need a script to watch directory..is this correct understanding?

Comment: @Aman exactly. i specified my problem with more details in the description of this post. hope this helps you to understand my problem better

Answer (score 0):

```
#Schedule below script in crontab for interval of 1 min or 5 min based on your requirement
#Update the parameters(HDFSLocation,FileName,etc) as per the requirement
#Update the script to trigger alert(send mail/trigger another script if newHDFSFileCount > #previousHDFSFileCount)

import subprocess
import os

#Parameters
cwd=os.getcwd()
file='HDFSFileCount.txt'
fileWithPath=cwd+"/"+file
HDFSLocation="/tmp"
previousHDFSFileCount=0
newHDFSFileCount=0
#Calculate New HDFS file count
out = subprocess.Popen(['hadoop','fs','-ls', '/tmp/'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
if out[0][0]==0:
        newHDFSFileCount=0
else:
        newHDFSFileCount=out[0][6]

#
if os.path.exists(fileWithPath):
        f=open(fileWithPath,"r")
        previousHDFSFileCount=f.read()
else:
        f=open(fileWithPath,"w+")
        f.write(newHDFSFileCount)
        previousHDFSFileCount=newHDFSFileCount

f.close()

if (newHDFSFileCount>previousHDFSFileCount):
        f=open(fileWithPath,"w")
        f.write(newHDFSFileCount)
        #print(previousHDFSFileCount)
        #print(newHDFSFileCount)
        f.close()
```